# how to create a relocatable rpm package , no compile

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I am trying to create a "relocatable RPM" of bunch of script and .png files. No build/compile. I wrote

```
    Name:       utp
    Version:    1.0
    Release:    1%{?dist}
    Summary:    some summary

    Group:      Applications/Engineering
    License:    Proprietary
    URL:        http://www.example.com
    Source0:    %{name}-%{version}.tgz
    BuildArch:  noarch
    Prefix:     /opt

    %description
    A very nice description

    %prep
    echo "=== prep ... done"

    %setup -n utp
    echo "=== setup ... done"

    # %files -f %{_tmppath}/files.list
    %files
```

and I get

```
    medi@medi:~/work> rpm -qi -p rpmbuild/RPMS/noarch/utp-1.0-1.el8.noarch.rpm 
    Name        : utp
    Version     : 1.0
    Release     : 1.el8
    Architecture: noarch
    Install Date: (not installed)
    Group       : Applications/Engineering
    Size        : 0
    License     : Proprietary
    Signature   : (none)
    Source RPM  : utp-1.0-1.el8.src.rpm
    Build Date  : Mon 17 Feb 2020 03:44:00 PM PST
    Build Host  : medi.example.com
    Relocations : /opt 
    URL         : http://www.example.com
    Summary     : some summary
    Description :
    A very nice description
```

and

```
    medi@medi:~/work> rpm -ql -p rpmbuild/RPMS/noarch/utp-1.0-1.el8.noarch.rpm 
    (contains no files)
    medi@medi:~/work>
```

Most likely the problem is with '%files'. I tried to specify a list (commented out now), but I ran into the following

```
    Processing files: utp-1.0-1.el8.noarch
    error: Directory not found: /home/medi/work/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/utp-1.0-1.el8.x86_64/opt/utp
    error: File not found: /home/medi/work/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/utp-1.0-1.el8.x86_64/opt/utp/utg
    error: File not found: /home/medi/work/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/utp-1.0-1.el8.x86_64/opt/utp/utg/UserGuide.txt
```

where my file.list looks like

```
    /opt/utp/
    /opt/utp/utg
    /opt/utp/utg/UserGuide.txt
    /opt/utp/utg/install.txt
```

Since I want to make this a relocatable one (see Prefix: /opt), I prepended '/opt'.

I think overall, I am confused. Yes I did read the doc, but I am missing it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The reason for pkg not having content is because %file directive was empty and with -f one has to be careful about where files are. After many reads, I figured that %files look for files in %{buildroot} by default so this combination solved it

```
%install 
cp -r ./* %{buildroot}

%files
/%{name}
```

So, now I have content, but then I ran into some shebang_mangling, where I had to disable that.

Comment: The expert with 60 reputation has spoken! The reason you should edit is because while we're helping you _today_, the point is to be a repository of information with Question and then Answer to help somebody _else_ next time.

Answer (score 0):

Your `%build` and `%install` stanzas should still exist; one unpacks your source of images and the other copies them to the final locations within the buildroot.